# Alternate for Input accessory view for Android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, inputaccessoryview

this is my code its working fine in ios but not on android is there any alternative of this for android (input accessory view

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {
         StyleSheet,
         InputAccessoryView,
         Button,
         FlatList, 
         TextInput, 
         ScrollView, 
         KeyboardAvoidingView,
         TouchableWithoutFeedback,
         Platform, 
         Keyboard, 
         View, 
         Text,
          }
from 'react-native';
import { KeyboardAwareFlatList } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
    
const ConnectWithPeople = () => {
   const [text, setText] = useState(initialText);

      return (
        <View style={styles.view}>
    
          <KeyboardAwareFlatList
            style={{ aspectRatio: 1 }}
            contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, }}
            data={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,]}
            renderItem={() => {
              return (
    
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', marginBottom: 10, height: 60 }}>
    
                </View>
    
              )
            }}
    
            ListFooterComponent={() => {
              return (
    
                <InputAccessoryView >
    
                  <TextInput style={styles.TextInput}
                    inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID}
                    onChangeText={setText()}
                    value={text}
                    placeholder="please type here..."
                  />
                </InputAccessoryView>
              )
            }}
    
          />
    
    
        </View>
    
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      },
      TextInput: {
        padding: 10,
        marginTop: 550,
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginRight: 10,
        maxWidth: 350,
        borderWidth: 1,
        },
        
        view: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: 6
         },
        });
```

Comment: The code as you have provided, does not compile.

Comment: sir you have to install the input accessory  package

Comment: also keyboardAwareFlat list package